# Laravel 4.1: Eloquent Offset & Limit

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

How to limit returned data from Eloquent? I tried with this:

```
$data = Product::all()->take(4)->skip(3);
```

And it return the error message: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::skip()`

It seems like eloquent don't support `skip()`? So, how can I offset & limit the data from eloquent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may try this (get 4 items from offset 3/4th):

```
Product::take(4)->offset(3)->get();
```

Or this (get 5 items from 3rd row):

```
Product::take(5)->skip(2)->get();
```

Comment: I may be crazy, but this doesn't work for me at all. I just get skip() and offset() not found.

Comment: Maybe you are not crazy but some crazy mistakes are happening that makes you think you are crazy, can you describe the situation with code ?

Comment: No situation at all. I've **never** gotten that to work. Brand spanking new model, that exact line (well, adjusted for the name of the model), error. take() works fine, but not skip() or offset()

Comment: Any error messages ? Did you turn on `debug => true` in `app/config/app.php` ?

Comment: I am crazy, apparently. It works now. I spent a week (well, not continuous) awhile back trying to make it work and kept getting errors. I tried it earlier, error. Now it works. I'm going to chalk it up to gremlins.

Comment: Like i said you are not crazy but we think us like that so we become, take it easy, something is not working, leave it for a while, try from the beginning later, it'll work. Thanks fir the thumbs up :-)

Answer (score 1):

laravel have own function skip for offset and take for limit. just like below example of laravel query :-

```
Product::where([['title','=',$text_val]])
                ->skip(0)
                ->take(2) //get first 2 rows
                ->get();
```