# Laravel : Eloquent Skip records

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How did i get my users but start only at a certain position ?
I get the 50 first with :

```
$users = User::orderBy('xp', 'DESC')->take(50)->get();
```

But now I want the 50 after this, so the 50th to 100th records.

Thanks

Comment: `$users = User::orderBy('xp', 'DESC')->skip(10)->take(5)->get();` skip is your offset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4.1: Eloquent Offset & Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923320/laravel-4-1-eloquent-offset-limit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `skip()`

Laravel eloqunt provides nice way to achieve this.

```
$users = User::orderBy('xp', 'DESC')->skip(50)->take(50)->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah ! Exactly. Thanks

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine I am glad it helped you. :)